# 2 joins on same table while summing amounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, psql

I've got 2 tables that I need to efficiently pull data out of.

```
TableA
id
full_name

TableB
table_a_id_1
table_a_id_2
amount1
amount2
```

TableB references two different records on TableA (they will never be the same)

I am trying to write 1 query (or the most efficient query, trying to avoid n+2 query) to get a list of all records in TableA with the totaled sums for corresponding TableB

It would look something like this:

```
[{id: 1, full_name: 'bob', 1_sum1: 50.0, 1_sum2: 30.0, 2_sum1: 1.0, 2_sum2: 25.0}]
```

where 
id and full_name is from TableA

1_sum1, 1_sum2, are both summed columns from TableB where table_a_id_1 = TableA.id

2_sum1, 2_sum2 are both summed columns from TableB where table_a_id_2 = TableA.id

I really hope this isn't confusing. I've got a query like this:

```
results = TableA.
joins('LEFT JOIN table_b t1_stats ON t1_stats.t1_aff_id = table_a.id').
joins('LEFT JOIN table_b t2_stats ON t2_stats.t2_aff_id = table_a.id').
select("table_a.*,
sum(t1_stats.amount1) AS 1_sum1,
sum(t2_stats.amount1) AS 2_sum1,
sum(t1_stats.amount2) AS 1_sum2,
sum(t2_stats.amount2) AS 2_sum2").
group('table_a.id')
```

I'm not getting results that are correct on the summed totals. I think its because it should be only summing records for 1_sum1 on records from table_b where table_a_id_1 = table_a.id and instead I think it might be including all records, then summing them.

Do I need to do a sub select or something instead? This is not my strong point here, so any help on getting this query sorted out would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
results = TableA.
select("table_a.*,
(SELECT sum(table_b.amount1) FROM table_b WHERE table_b.t1_aff_id = table_a.id) AS 1_sum1,
(SELECT sum(table_b.amount2) FROM table_b WHERE table_b.t1_aff_id = table_a.id) AS 1_sum2,
(SELECT sum(table_b.amount1) FROM table_b WHERE table_b.t2_aff_id = table_a.id) AS 2_sum1,
(SELECT sum(table_b.amount2) FROM table_b WHERE table_b.t2_aff_id = table_a.id) AS 2_sum2")
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm curious when I get hundreds of thousands of rows in table b, whether this will be efficient still. I actually have 8 columns total that I am summing from table b, so i think its doing 8 sub queries in that case. not sure if that will be a problem or not. Will have to try and test this. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure how it'll perform with a lot of rows - but I'd wait til you get to that point then optimise the query. If you found the answer useful, consider upvoting or marking as correct.